# How to convert a string into datetime format using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting date and time from datetime picker and I want to store this into database. Database field type= datetime. I am using ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime.parse('2015-06-20 15:15:15')
```